# Google Cloud Logging malfunctioning from cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

I am currently trying to deploy a cloud function triggered by Pub/Sub written in Python. Previously, we used loguru to log. I am now making the switch to the cloud logging. I thought it would be rather simple but am quite puzzled. Here is the code I deployed in a Cloud Function, just to try logging :

```
import base64
import logging
import google.cloud.logging as google_logging

def hello_pubsub(event, context):
     client = google_logging.Client()
     client.setup_logging()
     logging.debug("Starting function")
     logging.info("Hello")

     logging.warning("warning ! ")

     pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
     logging.info(pubsub_message)
     logging.error("Exit function")
```

I followed the documentation I could find on the subject (but the pages can show various methods, and are not very clear). Here is the result on the Logging interface :

[image: Resulting logs in "global" tab]

This is the result on the "Global" logs. Two questions here : why aren't the debug logs not shown, even if I explicitely set the log level as "debug" in the interface ? And why the logs are shown 1, 2 or 3 times, randomly ?

Now I try to display the logs for my Cloud Function only :

[image: Resulting logs in "Cloud Function" logs for my function]

This is getting worse, now the logs are displayed up to 5 times (and not even the same number of times than in the "Global" tab), the levels of informations are all wrong (logging.info results in 1 info line, 1 error line ; error and warning results in 2 errors lines...)

I imagine I must be doing something bad, but I can't see what, as what I am trying to do is fairly simple. Can somebody please help me ? Thanks !

EDIT : I did the mistake of putting the initialization of the client in the function, this explains that the logs were displayed more than once. One problem left is that the warnings are displayed as errors in the "Cloud Function" tabs, and displayed correctly in the "Global" tab. Do someone has an idea about this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your setup outside of the function:

```py
import base64
import logging
import google.cloud.logging as google_logging

client = google_logging.Client()
client.setup_logging()

def hello_pubsub(event, context):
     logging.debug("Starting function")
     logging.info("Hello")

     logging.warning("warning ! ")

     pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
     logging.info(pubsub_message)
     logging.error("Exit function")
```

As-is, you're adding new handlers on every request per instance.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it was the reason for the multiple messages.

Comment: No problem! If this solved your issue, don't forget to accept the answer. :)

Comment: This solved the half of it, I still don't know why some logs display with the bad level of info

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Integration with Python logging module¶](https://googleapis.dev/python/logging/latest/stdlib-usage.html)

```
import logging
import base64
import google.cloud.logging # Don't conflict with standard logging
from google.cloud.logging.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler
client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
handler = CloudLoggingHandler(client)
cloud_logger = logging.getLogger('cloudLogger')
cloud_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO) # defaults to WARN
cloud_logger.addHandler(handler)



def hello_pubsub(event, context):

     import logging
     cloud_logger.debug("Starting function")
     cloud_logger.info("Hello")

     cloud_logger.warning("warning ! ")

     pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
     cloud_logger.info(pubsub_message)
     cloud_logger.error("Exit function")

     return 'OK', 200
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this approach too but my mistake was putting all of the code in the function, resulting in multiple messages. Now this is much better, but the warning logs are still showing as errors (and are displayed correctly in the 'Global' tab.

Comment: The logs you are showing here are from Cloud Functions default integration with the python logging module.

The logs that OP is seeing in 'global' are the logs coming from the CloudLoggingHandler()

Comment: Could it be that this is outdated? At `handler = CloudLoggingHandler(client)` I get the error `File "/workspace/main.py", line 495, in MY_FUNCTION.setup_logging(handler) TypeError: setup_logging() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. I am using the same settings in a Python 3.9 cloud function. I have read somewhere that the handler is somehow not needed anymore with in recent `google.cloud.logging`, but I cannot find that anymore and I am not sure.